# Cannot decode BASE64 to Image file in Selenium 2

Tags: java, base64, screenshot, selenium-webdriver, decode

I have a BASE64 image from a screenshot capture that I would like to convert in a image.png file but there are compilation errors that I cannot understand.

```
    Object ss = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BASE64);
    Base64 decoder = new Base64();
    Byte[] imgBytes = (Byte[]) decoder.decode(ss);
    FileOutputStream osf = new FileOutputStream(new File("./screenshots/"+ System.getProperty("logfilename") + ".png"));        
    osf.write(imgBytes);
    osf.flush();
```

The compilation error in the code above is in the line osf.write(imgBytes) where it tells me that write() method will not accept Byte[] object because it tells me that the method only accepts write(int i) args. It is weird because when you see the options there is a write(Byte[] b).

Could you help me solve this riddle?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to save it as a file, you should just use the `OutputFile.FILE` enum. That essentially wraps the decoding for you.

Answer (score 1):

The write func takes the primitive byte and not the wrapper class i.e. **byte[]**  and not Byte[]. So the compiler error..